# Does bas64 encoding display digits?

Tags: php, base64, encode

Whatever I encode will base64 encoding display numbers and digits in the output or will it show only letters in php ?

Comment: Did you try encoding a string and see what you got?

Comment: yes i encoded a string, i got only characters .....i want to make sure it will happen with any string !!

Answer (score 0):

No it will not.

Base64 can include numbers as well as letters.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64